# Give the generator polynomial of a binary cyclic [9, 2] code.

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

I'm new to Cyclic Codes and I'm not sure the process to find a generator polynomial of a cyclic code. I know what a cyclic code is, but not sure how to find a generator polynomial. Since the question states give THE generator polynomial, I'm assuming there is only one correct answer. Can anyone help my or point me on the right path? After that I also need to find the generator matrix, check polynomial, and check matrix for the code. If anyone could help me with that as well that would be great. I'm trying to use the Introduction to the Theory of Error-Correcting Codes by Vera Pless, but it's not helping much. Thanks again!

Comment: The polynomial generators of cyclic codecs of length $n$ are divisors of $x^n-1$. In this case you know that the dimension of the code is $2$, so the generator polynomial $g(x)$ has degree $7$ (if there happens to be two different polynomials of degree $7$ which divide $x^9-1$, then 'the' is wrong. Then $x^n-1=g(x)h(x)$ and $h(x)$ will be your check polynomial. See theorems 49 and 51.

Comment: I'm probably way off here, but would g(x) = x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1?

Comment: That choice of $g(x)$ divides $x^9-1$ and it follows that $h(x)=x^2-x+1$.But I don't know if these are the only possible choices.

Comment: I simply factored x^9 - 1, getting (x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1). Then the only possible combination that equals degree 7 is (x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)

Comment: I'm too lazy to factor it. If that's correct, then yes, it's fine.

Comment: @GitGud : perhaps you should move your comments to an answer?

Comment: @leonbloy Perhaps I should. I tend not to give answers to new users, (in the form of actual answers I mean). I will not move the comments to an answer because I wouldn't be  satisfied with them being answer (because of stuff like me not having even factored $x^9-1$).

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin If no one else answers, I'd like to ask you to answer your question yourself so it doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: FWIW I checked the factors of $x^9-1$ over $GF(2)$ and they're correct.